# List of Strings - Odd Behavior

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, contains, string-concatenation

I'm working on an obscenity filter for a random word generator so that it avoids certain words or phrases. The code is fairly simple so far and I'm using some test words to try it out, yet there is already a strange error occurring that makes absolutely no sense to me.

```
final List<String> obscene;

WordEngine(){
    obscene = new ArrayList<>();
    loadObscene();
    System.out.println(isObscene("otestingo"));
}

void loadObscene(){
    try {
        InputStream configStream = Interactions.class.getResourceAsStream("obscene.txt");
        Scanner fileScanner = new Scanner(configStream);
        fileScanner.useDelimiter("\\n");
        String nextWord;
        while(fileScanner.hasNext()){
            nextWord = fileScanner.next();
            obscene.add(nextWord);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    //for(String obsceneIterator : obscene){ System.out.println(obsceneIterator); }
}

boolean isObscene(String word){
    for (Iterator<String> it = obscene.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        String nextObscene = it.next();
        String test = nextObscene;
        System.out.println(test);
        System.out.println(test + " " + word);
        if(word.contains(nextObscene)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

The text file contains:

```
words
for
testing
```

The output is:

```
words
otestingo
for
otestingo
testing
otestingo
false
```

The expected output would be:

```
words
words otestingo
for
for otestingo
testing
testing otestingo
true
```

Something about concatenating the string or accessing it is causing it to be deleted. I've tried every sort of probing that I can think of and am not finding any way to make sense of the discrepancy between what I expect and what I get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using UNIX line endings (`\n`) in your text file, your program produces the output you expect.  If however you use dos line endings, you (almost) get the output you describe.  The true output I see is:

```
words
 otestingo
for
 otestingo
testing
 otestingo
false
```

You're probably not on a UNIX derivative OS - and I don't know what a Windows tool to convert line endings is - but if you have Vim you can use the command `ff=unix` and write the file back to change the line endings.

Alternatively, you can simply remove this line:

```
fileScanner.useDelimiter("\\n");
```

... and the scanner will correctly deal with your dos line endings.

Comment: Respect. How did you figure that out?!

Comment: When the program worked for me, I had a hunch the text file probably had non-UNIX line endings.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! I knew there was some extra information being stored in that string somehow that was causing the strange output, and I knew it had something to do with the scanner. I never would have thought that my delimiter was causing the issue. I'm running on Windows 8.